# Moderator election 2023 - community interest check

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderators, election

We have had a moderator step down, so currently are running with just 2. Now, the good thing is that generally this site runs without too much moderator involvement - the community generally has things in hand.

That said, this is an opportunity to have an election in the near future.

To avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail due to an insufficient number of candidates, though, I'm posting this to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves, when the actual election's nomination period starts.

Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, should we decide to run an election.

NOTE: This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up, so you don't have to put up your whole election nomination.